# ASP.NET Delete Row from DataTable

Tags: asp.net, datatable, shopping-cart, datarow

I`m working ona shopping cart. I have a page with my products and the "add to cart" button. When I click the button I pass the prodict Id as a DataTable using a Session["Cart"].
On the Cart.aspx I retrive the Session like this:

```
    if (Session["Cart"] != null)
    {
        dtCart = Session["Cart"] as DataTable;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtCart.Rows)
        {
            string SQL = "SELECT p.Id, p.Name, c.Name, p.Descr,  p.Price, p.ImagePath FROM Categories AS c JOIN Products AS p ON (c.Id = p.CategoryId) WHERE p.Id=@ID;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", dr["ProductId"]);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    dlCart.DataSource = dt;
    dlCart.DataBind();
```

I can see all of the products, the problem start when I want to delete a product from the Cart.
Inside the DataList I have a LinkButton with the CommandName "delete".
This is my method:

```
    protected void dlCart_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string ProductID = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
    if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {
        for(int i = dtCart.Rows.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtCart.Rows[i];
            if(dr["ProductId"].ToString() == ProductID)
            {
                dtCart.Rows.Remove(dr);

            }
        }
    }

    dlCart.EditItemIndex = -1;
    BindDlCart();
}
```

Like I said I have 2 issues here:

1. When I click on the LinkButton the Menu on the top of the page multiply itself (the menu is database driven using an ASP.NET Menu Control)
2. When I click on the "delete" nothing happens ...
   I get a PostBack and nothing happens.

I would really aprriciate the help!

Comment: So `dlCart_ItemCommand` is not triggered? Have you used the debugger? Do you call `BindDlCart` in `Page_Load` without `if(!IsPostBack)...`? According to the other issue "page multiply itself", you should only ask one question. Create another question for that issue.

Comment: Apart from that, do you want to remove that DataRow from the `DataTable` (like you do) or do you actually want to delete this row from your database table?